# How to get all photos moment wise using ALAssetLibrary in ios7?

Tags: ios, iphone, alassetslibrary, alasset, alassetsgroup

I have problem to get photos in moment wise like apple iphone have in ios8. I have implemented for ios8 using PHAsset and Photos.framework. Now, when i run same code in ios7 device then it returns nothing. So, i go with ALAssetLibrary to get photos. Using ALAssetLibrary i also got all photos but that are like albums wise photos. and also using this ALAssetLibrary i cannot get album creation date not its location name, as i have to show this to data on my each section's header.

My code for fetching photos in ios7 using ALAssetLibrary:

```
        _imagearray = [@[] mutableCopy];
        __block NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];

        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
         {
             if (group)
             {
                 [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];
                 [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                     if (asset!=nil)
                     {
                         [tmpAssets addObject:asset];

                     }
                 }];
             }
             self.imagearray = tmpAssets;
             NSLog (@“%@“,self.imagearray);
         }
                                  failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
         }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found its solutions my self.

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library;
}

-(void)loadAssets{
    NSMutableArray *unSortArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [MomentsVCTR defaultAssetsLibrary];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (group == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Done!");
            [self manageLocalAssets:unSortArray];
        }
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];
        [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {
            if (alAsset) {
                [unSortArray addObject:alAsset];
            }

        }];
    } failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"No groups: %@",error);
    }];
}

-(void)manageLocalAssets:(NSMutableArray*)unSortArray{
    NSMutableArray *_resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    NSLog(@"in loadassets");
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
    NSArray *reverseOrder=[unSortArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    for (int k=0; k<reverseOrder.count; k++) {
        ALAsset *asset = (ALAsset *)[reverseOrder objectAtIndex:k];
        NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]];
        if (![self.arrDate containsObject:dateStr]) {
            [self.arrDate addObject:dateStr];
            [self.arrEventID addObject:@"0"];
            [self.arrEventName addObject:@"0"];
        }
        [_resultArray addObject:asset];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<self.arrDate.count;i++) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int tPhoto = 0;
        int tVideo = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<_resultArray.count; j++) {
            ALAsset *asset = (ALAsset*)[_resultArray objectAtIndex:j];
            NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]];
            if ([[self.arrDate objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:dateStr]) {
                UIImage *latestPhotoThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
                [arr addObject:latestPhotoThumbnail];
                latestPhotoThumbnail = nil;
                if ([[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                    [arr2 addObject:@"1"];
                    tVideo++;
                }
                else{
                    [arr2 addObject:@"0"];
                    tPhoto++;
                }
                NSDate *date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
                [self.imageDateArray addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
                [self.imageIdArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
            }
        }
        [self.imagearray addObject:arr];
        [self.arrContentType addObject:arr2];

        [self.momentArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)arr.count]];
        [self.arrPhotoCount addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tPhoto]];
        [self.arrVideoCount addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tVideo]];
    }
    [self setButtonsSize];
    self.collection.dataSource = self;
    self.collection.delegate = self;
    [self.collection reloadData];
    [self.collection.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    self.footerView.hidden = TRUE;
    self.footerWebView.hidden = TRUE;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck with iOS 7. AssetsLibrary as you observed returns only albums (Camera Roll, user albums). Even though the Photos App in iOS 7 shows Moments, there are no developer APIs in iOS 7 to get Moments.

Comment: Yes, thats true, and i have also managed this in iOS8, but iOS 7 i haven't found any solution for it.

Comment: The only thing you could do: Scan the entire photo library yourself and then create a moments like structure (either in memory or in a datastructure/database on disk). However, this will be quite slow if the user has a lot of photos. Also, you need to rescan the entire library every time as AssetsLibrary has no methods to find out, which assets have been added or deleted, when the app is not running.