# Photo library display empty in some devices using ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
// photo gallary or from library  

NSUInteger groupTypes;
groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAlbum  | ALAssetsGroupLibrary  |        ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos | ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream  ;
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes usingBlock:listGroupBlock      failureBlock:failureBlock];
```

I am trying to fetch images libraries from iPad devices using ALAssetsLibrary. From all the fetched libraries, "Photo library" shows empty in some devices.

Comment: FYI - Unless you have a need to support iOS 7, you should not be using `ALAssetLibrary`. You should be using the newer Photos framework.

Comment: My app support iOS 8 and above. Can you please tell me the Photo framework that will support my app

Comment: It's all in the documentation for the Photos framework.

Comment: okay thanks @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream` then it will return asset-url but cannot generate image from that url. Because stream assets are not storing their bitmap.

Instead you should avoid that and get only those images which are store in device.

add this line where you allocate your ALAssetsLibrary.

```
[ALAssetsLibrary disableSharedPhotoStreamsSupport];
```

It will not return shared stream photos which are nil.

Comment: Please take a look of my answer on same type of questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858189/how-to-get-all-photos-moment-wise-using-alassetlibrary-in-ios7/28644922#28644922